# Check for character format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

probably an obvious question but Oracle Technet is not being friendly with my search terms on this. I want create a table and have a char column have a specific format. For example, a check constraint that would make sure the inserted SSN string is in the format "###-##-####" including the dashes. How do I specify this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not a very good idea to store the data in a specific format. Formatting is just bells and whistles and different situations may need different formats. Add localization to this and it becomes more obvious that this is not be a great idea.

You would want to format after retrieving the data. This can be done by [Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).

Comment: Well best practices aside, the format for the data will always be the same. Though I suppose I can do the check elsewhere instead of in the insert, I just thought it would be nice to make the table only accept that format since it is going to be a static string.

Answer (score 2):

I never done something like it, but try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
(   supplier_id numeric(4), 
    supplier_name   varchar2(50),   
    CONSTRAINT check_supplier_id
        CHECK (supplier_id REGEXP_LIKE(testcol, '^... .. ....$');)
);
```

Comment: Probably works, but i'm not going to run regex if that's the only option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

More complex validations can be done using database triggers. Maybe you that's the search term you missed.