# how to add check constraint in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraint

I have a table,

```
create table a(
id_a number(5) not null, 
name varchar2(15) not null, 
address varchar2(30), 
phone varchar2(15), 
constraint pk_a primary key (id_a)
);
```

I want add constraint check at phone. 
example. phone is 08175210868

I want to only be input with +628175210868

sorry my bad english.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606552/check-for-character-format-in-oracle) thread for possible solutions. Also you could already gave a try searching SO for possible answers.

Comment: I guess you have a typo, both the numbers are completely different. `752` or `725`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a row-level trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VALIDATE_PHONE 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF PHONE ON A 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    ex_phone       EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.PHONE not like '+62%' THEN raise ex_phone; END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below

```
alter table b add constraint phone check (phone like '+62%');
```